# The last term of the series $x^2,x,1\cdots$ to 31 terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The last term of the series 
$$x^2,\ x,\ 1\ ... 
$$to $31$ terms is

1.) $\ x^{28}$

2.) $\ 1/x$

3.) $\ 1/x^{28}$

Comment: I'd say $x^-28$ but that doesn't seem one of the options. Also, option (1) and (3) are the same

Comment: that is similar to option 3 and that's right as mentioned in my book.Would you solve it for me please ?

Comment: Note that you divide each time by $x$. This means that $a_{n+1} = a_n / x$.

Comment: I see, it's changed now. Were did you get stuck? What were your own ideas on this?

Comment: @vrugtehagel even before the edit, the options all appeared different... and remember that $x^{-n}=1/x^n$

Comment: @JMoravitz in that case I must've missed the $1/$ part. I'm perfectly aware that $1/a^n$=$a^{-n}$.

Comment: I am doing Chartered Accountancy. I copied question from my book they mentioned answer but solution isn't here. I am unable to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series shown is a geometric progression where each term is related to the previous by a common multiplier (as opposed to an arithmetic progression with a common difference.)

Each term is given by $T_n = ar^{n-1}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio i.e. $\displaystyle\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$.

In this case we have $r=\displaystyle\frac{x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}$ and $a = x^2$.

So putting $n=31$ we have $\displaystyle T_{31}=x^2(\frac{1}{x})^{31-1} = x^{2-30}=x^{-28}$ or $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^{28}}$

Answer (score 1):

Every term is the previous divided by $x$. So, the first term is $x^2$, thus the second is $x^2/x=x$, the next is $x/x=1$, etc. Thus, the $31$st term is $1/x^{28}$ as described by option (3).

May I add, there is no general way to "solve" these kind of questions. Finding the correct answer is just a matter of using logic and common sense to find the least complicated pattern that suits the first couple terms, and for which (if it's a multiple choice question) the corresponding answer is actually an option.

Comment: That's clear now thanks buddy (; @vrugtehagel

Comment: If I've answered your question, consider marking this or the other answer as "correct" to keep answered questions from flooding the "unanswered" section of this website.